# Problema al clonar un proyecto con git en windows: Filename too long

Tags: git, windows10

Estaba tratando de clonar mi proyecto open source en Windows 10, pero obtuve el siguiente error:

> fatal: cannot create directory at 'node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/got/node_modules/duplexify/node_modules/end-of-stream/node_modules/once/node_modules/wrappy': Filename too long
>
> warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
>
> You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
>
> and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

La carpeta donde estoy tratando de clonar es:

```
C:\Users\MiNombreDeUsuarioQueNoTieneEspacios\IdeaProjects
```

¿Hay alguna forma de habilitar las rutas largas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basándome en [esta respuesta de iveqy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows) procedí del modo siguiente:

1.- Busqué en mi Windows la ruta de instalación de git:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc
```

Donde se localiza un archivo que se llama **gitconfig** el cual tiene una estructura como la siguiente:

```
[http]
    sslBackend = openssl
    sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
[diff "astextplain"]
    textconv = astextplain
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge --skip -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process --skip
    required = true
[core]
    editor = \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Sublime Text 3\\\\subl.exe\" -w
    longpaths = false
[credential]
    helper = manager
```

La parte que nos interesa modificar a nivel de *core* se llama **longpaths**, por *defecto* se encuentra a `false` lo podemos cambiar aquí de forma manual y guardar los cambios o podemos guiarnos como nos indican en la respuesta por medio del siguiente comando:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

> Me centré en la parte de la solución, sin embargo el *origen del problema* que es necesario de conocer para conocer en profundidad se consigue en el enlace marcado que me dió pie para otorgar esta *respuesta*

Answer (score 4):

Sucede debido a una limitación general de Windows que reconoce, por defecto, la longitud de las rutas hasta 260 caracteres.
Una forma para que git reconozca las rutas largas es (Como administrador):

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Si es solo para clonar el repositorio, sin afectar la configuración general de git

```
git clone -c core.longpaths=true <repo-url>
```

Para que Windows 10 reconozca las rutas largas permanentemente, desde el editor de registro (regedit)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem -> LongPathsEnabled: 1
```

[Filename too long in Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows)
[How to fix “Filename too long error” during git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699177/how-to-fix-filename-too-long-error-during-git-clone)